# How to show WooCommerce new user registrations in Wordpress Dashboard widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I would like to create a wordpress dashboard widget which shows WooCommerce registered user at dashboard.

Currently using his code

```php
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'register_my_dashboard_widget' );
function register_my_dashboard_widget() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'my_dashboard_widget',
        'My Dashboard Widget',
        'my_dashboard_widget_display'
    );

}

function my_dashboard_widget_display() {
    echo 'the context here';
}
```

I have created a widget but don't know how to show registered user there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment with explanation added in the code.

Functions used:

- [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) - Retrieve list of users matching criteria. [`$args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/)
- [`wp_dashboard_setup()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dashboard_setup/) - Registers dashboard widgets.

```php
function action_wp_dashboard_setup() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( 
        'my_dashboard_widget', // Widget slug. 
        esc_html__( 'My Dashboard Widget', 'woocommerce' ), // Title
        'my_dashboard_widget_function' // Display function
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'action_wp_dashboard_setup' );

function my_dashboard_widget_function() {
    // Args
    $args = array(
        'role_in'  => array( 'administrator', 'customer'), // user roles
        'orderby'  => 'user_registered',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'number'   => -1 // all
    );

    // Get users
    $users = get_users( $args );

    // Output
    echo '<div class="main">';
    echo '<ul>';

    // True
    if ( $users ) {
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {
            echo '<li>User name = ' .  $user->display_name . '</li>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<li>no users found</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked applied some css and VOILA it's amazing. Thank you for help.